# TypeError: this.subClient.psubscribe is not a function

Tags: sockets, redis

Here's the init of the redis pubClient and subClient:

[image: here's the init of the redis pubClient and subClient]

onConnection event with socket:

[image: onConnection event with socket]

I'm trying to initialize the Redis in every socket connection :

```
this.subClient.psubscribe(this.channel + "*", onError);
```

However I get:

> TypeError: this.subClient.psubscribe is not a function

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Please post code, error messages, markup, data structures, and other textual information **as text**, not just as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Answer (score 1):

As TJ mentioned, inline code would be much, much better. You should revise your question to include that. That said, I looked at your code and I see two problems.

1. You haven't opened your Redis connect. Instructions on how to do this can be found at the [top of the README](https://github.com/redis/node-redis#basic-example) for Node Redis. I've pasted it below for your convenience, but you'll want to go over the [README](https://github.com/redis/node-redis) for more details:

```js
import { createClient } from 'redis';

const client = createClient();

client.on('error', (err) => console.log('Redis Client Error', err));

await client.connect();
```

2. The method is `pSubscribe` not `psubscribe`. Examples for Redis Pub/Sub are also in [the README](https://github.com/redis/node-redis#pubsub), albeit a bit further down. Here's the salient bits:

```js
const subscriber = client.duplicate();
await subscriber.connect();

await subscriber.pSubscribe('channe*', (message, channel) => {
  console.log(message, channel); // 'message', 'channel'
});

await subscriber.pUnsubscribe('channe*');
```

Hope this helps and, please, help future readers by inlining your code. Thanks!